# Simple Nested loop with Python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I have two simple text files where I am trying to compare them line by line to see which lines in file 1 don't appear in file 2. I've tried a couple different options from what I've read for similar questions on this site, but I still can't get it to work.  Any suggestions would be welcome. Here is my code:

```
listNames = raw_input("Which is list1?")
list2Names = raw_input("Which is list2?")
data1 = open(listNames)
data2 = open(list2Names)
data = []

source1 = data1.readlines()
source2 = data2.readlines()


for line in source1:
    temp1 = line.rstrip()   
    inList = False
    for ln2 in source2:
        temp2 = ln2.rstrip()
        if temp1 == temp2:      
            inList == True  #edit2: oops
    if inList == False:
        data.append(temp1)

for x in data:
    print x
```

From testing my code it looks like the second If Statement isn't been accessed at all.

edit: corrected a line

Comment: Just a quick tip, your checking of == True and == False is a very bad idea. It is against the rules and can be misinterpret by Python too.
Use if inList: in place of if inList == True. It does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Python `set()` type to hold the data elements from each list, then you can get the set difference (i.e., those elements that occur in the first but not the second list) by using the `-` operator:

```
data1 = set(l.rstrip() for l in open(raw_input("Which is list1?")))
data2 = set(l.rstrip() for l in open(raw_input("Which is list2?")))
for x in data1 - data2:
     print x
```

The first two lines here load data from the first and second files, by treating the file handle (the return value from the call to `open(...)`) as an iterator, and adding information from each file directly to a set object.

If you need to compute the set difference manually, using for loops, then you can use Python's `any` function to test for membership:

```
data1 = list(l.rstrip() for l in open(raw_input("Which is list1?")))
data2 = list(l.rstrip() for l in open(raw_input("Which is list2?")))
data = []
for x in data1:
    if not any(x == y for y in data2):
        data.append(x)
for x in data:
    print x
```

The file handles returned by `open(...)` will get cleaned up by the garbage collector eventually, but for "real" code it's a better idea to use the `with` statement when dealing with files. For example, to build the source lists from the above code, use:

```
data1 = []
with open(raw_input("Which is list1?")) as handle:
    data1.extend(l.rstrip() for l in handle)
# ...
```

The `with` statement will close the file handles for you once the indented block is complete.

Comment: Wow thanks, that is way simpler than what I was trying to do. Just a quick question, how would I close the files? Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: check out 'with' keyword https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html and Set types https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20union#set

Comment: I'll update the answer with an example of the `with` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your second if statement isn't accessed because you have a typo:

```
inList == True
```

should be

```
inList = True
```

**Edit:**

Also you might consider this instead of your solution:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        diff = set(line.rstrip() for line in file1).difference(line.rstrip() for line in file2)
```

diff variable will contain a set with all lines that were in file1 but not in file2

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I posted this. Unfortunately my code still doesn't work as intended

Edit...nevermind I'm an idiot. I see what you are saying